# Eclipse JVM terminated.Exit code = 1.Null pointer Exception.Not able to start the eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I get error like

**Internal Error :Null Pointer Exception**

> **JVM terminated. Exit code=1**
>   /usr/bin/java
>   -Xms256M
>   -Xmx1024M
>   -jar /opt/eclipse-installer//plugins  /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>   -os linux
>   -ws gtk
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash
>   -launcher /opt/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst
>   -name Eclipse Installer
>   --launcher.library /opt/eclipse-installer//plugins  /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417  /eclipse_1612.so
>   -startup /opt/eclipse-installer//plugins   /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -exitdata 6d8015
>   -data @none
>   -vm /usr/bin/java
>   -vmargs
>   -Xms256M
>   -Xmx1024M
>   -jar /opt/eclipse-installer//plugins  /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
>
> **My Java version is**
>     Java version "1.8.0_65"
>     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
>     Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this one

```
C:\dev\IDE\eclipse332\eclipse.exe -vm C:\dev\JDK\j2sdk1.4.2_06\bin\javaw.exe  -vmargs -Xmx1024M -Xms512M
```

may be it is problem with memory.

Comment: Ya .I am working on ubuntu14.04 .Where I should hit this command.